# Web Service Client - Multiple HTTP Keep Alive Connection to same destination

Tags: java, web-services, http

We have a web service client applications that have too many requests to be processed on a single keep-alive connection.

Thus, we would like to create **multiple keep-alive connection**.

I am using the CXF HTTP Conduit to connect where **all endpoint, service name, port name are identical**. How do I specify this request to be send on **"connection B"** instead of "connection A" ?

I am now having a problem where it send to "connection A" instead of "connection B".

```
Client client = ((org.apache.cxf.jaxws.DispatchImpl) dispatch).getClient();
HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

conduit.getClient().setConnection(ConnectionType.KEEP_ALIVE); 
conduit.getClient().setReceiveTimeout(0);
conduit.getClient().setConnectionTimeout(0);

TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters = new TLSClientParameters();
tlsClientParameters.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
tlsClientParameters.setDisableCNCheck(true);

conduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsClientParameters);
```

Comment: Please feel free to provide any feedback.

Comment: Hi All, feel free to provide any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean that when you enable keep-alive, Tomcat gets overloaded because there are too many sockets.  Tomcat has two settings to limit the number of keep-alive sessions.  The first is the maximum number of keep-alive sessions, which defaults to 100, but you can lower that using system property:

```
server.tomcat.max-keep-alive-requests
```

Set this to a lower value than 100, until your server never uses too many keep-alive sockets.  Once you have that set to the correct maximum value, you should look at:

```
server.tomcat.keep-alive-timeout
```

- which decides how long a keep-alive session is kept around for.  Reducing this time (in msec, not in seconds) will prioritize clients that are sending requests frequently over clients that are not.  The default is 60000 (1 minute).

PS You haven't said which webserver you are using, but the default is Tomcat, so I assume you are using Tomcat, otherwise there are similar settings for eg Jetty.

The above should solve your problem, but if it does not, then you can still configure failover logic as follows:

```
  // 5 attempts, connect timeout 5 seconds, receive timeout 20 seconds (per attempt)
  // Should take about 30 seconds to fail if the server is completely down
  final RetryStrategy retryStrategy = new RetryStrategy();
  retryStrategy.setMaxNumberOfRetries(5);
  retryStrategy.setDelayBetweenRetries(1000);
  FailoverFeature failoverFeature = new FailoverFeature();
  failoverFeature.setStrategy(retryStrategy);
  failoverFeature.setTargetSelector(new FailoverTargetSelector(address));
  jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.getFeatures().add(failoverFeature);
  serviceBean = jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create();

  HTTPConduitConfigurer httpConduitConfigurer = (name, address, c) ->
  {
     HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
     httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
     httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(20000);
     c.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
  };

  Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(serviceBean);
  client.getBus().setExtension(httpConduitConfigurer, HTTPConduitConfigurer.class);
```